# the meaning of "in" function in awk

Tags: awk

I don't really understand the phrase `in` in awk code, i.e

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{
      band[$2]++
  }
  END{
    print "Band | Sum"
      for (x in band){
        print x" | " band[x]
      }
  }'
```

and

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){if($i in a)sub($i,a[$i],$i)}print}' OFS="|" lookupfile contentfile
```

what does it do if the phrase is `if($x in array)` and `for(x in array)`?

Answer (score 1):

From `man awk`:

> The special operator **in** may be used to test if an array has an
>   index consisting of a particular value:

```
if (val in array)
   print array[val]
```

> If the array has multiple subscripts, use **(i, j)** in array.
>
> The **in** construct may also be used in a for loop to iterate over
>   all elements of an array.

---

So your script:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{
      band[$2]++
  }
  END{
    print "Band | Sum"
      for (x in band){
        print x" | " band[x]
      }
  }'
```

Does the following:

- `band[$2]++` Creates an array `band` in which you store a counter of how many times each 2nd field appears.
- `for (x in band)` loop through the elements in the array `band` to do some stuff with them. Note the `for (x in band)` allows you to do something with the element `x` as index and `band[x]` as value.

Answer (score 0):

its just like any other language within a for loop.  The "in" just means you have a counter and it will go through each element within "band"

so when you print band[x] it is like saying print the element IN band where ever the counter is.

Comment: Comparing the `in` operator to a counter is a bad analogy as a counter implies a linearly incrementing order. Also it's doubly misleading since awk array elements are always strings, never integers.

Answer (score 0):

`in` means two different things in those case.  First:

```
if($i in a)sub($i,a[$i],$i)}print
```

In this form, `$i in a` is a logical test.  It returns true if `$i` is one of the keys of array `a` and returns false otherwise.

Second:

```
for (x in band){
        print x" | " band[x]
      }
```

In this form, the statement `print x" | " band[x]` is run once for `x` assigned to each of the keys of the array `a`.

#### Examples

Consider a file with the contents:

```
abc
def
hij
```

Now, let's run an `awk` command with the `for (x in a)` construct:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=NR} END{for (x in a) print "a[" x "]="a[x]}' file
a[def]=2
a[hij]=3
a[abc]=1
```

The first part, `a[$1]=NR` creates an array `a` whose keys are the first word on the line, `$1`, and whose values are the number of the record (line) on which the word occurred, `NR`.

The `for` loop goes over every key of the array.  It does not go through them, though, in any particular order.

Now, let's add one `if` condition to the above code.  We will use `if ("klm" in a) {...}`:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=NR} END{if ("klm" in a) {for (x in a) print "a[" x "]="a[x]}}' file
```

The above produces no output.  This is because array `a` has not such key as `klm`.

If, instead, we had written `if ("abc" in a) {...}`, then there would be output:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=NR} END{if ("abc" in a) {for (x in a) print "a[" x "]="a[x]}}' file
a[def]=2
a[hij]=3
a[abc]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there's a book that explains it all, Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins. You'll be interested in these sections of it:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reference-to-Elements

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array